# ¿Cómo alinear los item de dropdown-menu a la izquierda?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Que tal amigos de esta comunidad, vengo con un detalle de un `dropdown-menu` el cual al momento de desplegar los item se posicionan al lado derecho y quiero que se posicionen al lado izquierdo.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/03cf5139f1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css" />
    <title>Diseño y Soluciones</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <!--ENCABEZADO--> 
   <header></header> 

   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background: rgb(51, 71, 86)">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Diseño y Soluciones</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Portafolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Conocenos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Servicios
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Diseño gráfico</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Marketing digital</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Diseño web</a></li> 
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!--<form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que ingresar a la clase `.dropdown-menu` y darle la siguiente propiedad para que se alinee a la izquierda:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

Código completo:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/03cf5139f1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css" />
    <title>Diseño y Soluciones</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <!--ENCABEZADO--> 
   <header></header> 

   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background: rgb(51, 71, 86)">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Diseño y Soluciones</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Portafolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Conocenos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Servicios
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Diseño gráfico</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Marketing digital</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Diseño web</a></li> 
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!--<form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>


    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias ya tiene años que no entraba al diseño web.

Comment: Bienvenido nuevamente, éxitos!!